# Firebase add to if data does not exist

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

first time asker, so here it goes. I'm trying to write some Java for Android and Firebase where I need to check if an event record exists, and then adding it to a child if it does not exist. I currently am using one node for storing specific details on events, and the other node for just the city information.

This is what my database looks like:

```
App: {
  Details: {
       eventName: Name
       eventType: Type
       eventCity: Location
       etc, etc...
  }

 OnlyCities: {

 }
```

This is to check and add only new entries to OnlyCities list:

```
appRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            onlyCitiesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        if (!data.hasChild(eventCity)) {
                            onlyCitiesRef.push().setValue(eventCity);
                        }

                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "City already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
```

My problem is that I cannot check OnlyCities to see if something exists in there because the trigger for EventListener is onDataChange, and if I won't add data without checking, then there will never be a "data change"!

Can someone give me some guidance on how to get around this? Is there any way to get a datasnapshot without having to fire a listener?

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/numchildren.html
getting children number would fix it i suppose. good luck

Comment: It sounds like you're looking to run a transaction, which combines the read and write into a single operation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions